# Hover bar instead of pushing content

Tags: css, html, hover

I'd like the CookieBar to hover above the content of the body instead of pushing i all down. What CSS changes is needed to accomplish this? See the link for an example of how it looks.

http://www.primebox.co.uk/examples/cookie-bar/1/

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: I tried this and it kind of did the trick. Ok way to go about?

position:relative; float: left; width: 100%;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it a position:fixed property:

```
#cookie-bar {
    background: #111111;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: #eeeeee;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 3px 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Note `position: absolute` could work too. but with fixed the div stays up even when you scroll.

Comment: That was nice! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change first line in file jquery.cookiebar.css

```
#cookie-bar {background:#111111; height:24px; line-height:24px; color:#eeeeee; text-align:center; padding:3px 0;}
```

to

```
#cookie-bar {background:#111111; height:24px; line-height:24px; color:#eeeeee; text-align:center; padding:3px 0; position: absolute; width: 100%}
```